# UIWebView How to resize Word Document?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, ms-word

So I am receiving a payload of data from a webservice, one part is a MS-Word Doc and the other payload is a PDF.  the PDF loads into my UIWebView with out any issues, but when I go to load my MS-Word doc I get the right outer most part of the screen when it's truncated (not fully rendered) I can't zoom out to see more or anything.

my load code looks like this:

```
        strFilename = [strFilename stringByAppendingString:@"."];
        strFilename = [strFilename stringByAppendingString:extension];  
        NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* foofile = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFilename];
        [data writeToFile:foofile atomically:YES];

        BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:foofile];
        if (fileExists) {
            [myWebView loadRequest:request];
        }
```

I haven't had any problems with PDFs but with Word even though the code works and the data loads, only the right most 2% is sliced off and it's annoying to my users.

any idea on how to get the entire document to load correctly into a UIWebView (or should I be using a different view Controller?

Comment: Since PDF types seem to render ok can you just convert the word file to PDF?

Comment: unfortunately it's not possible, the files are being generated from our ERP system and some files are word while others are PDF. :(

Comment: Okay so you cannot save the doc to TEMP, convert it to PDF (many ways of doing that) - just as a mechanism for viewing the file, but not 'changing' the original copy on them?

Comment: If UIWebView relies on the web browser (I just assume it does), make sure its not a particular browser flavor that is causing the problem either. For example, can you open up the file in the default web browser on the machine, and it loads as desired.

Comment: jJack, thanks for following up.  I took at look at how this might be possible from the ERP system (convert to PDF), but my co-workers tell me that it's tricky in that platform, I don't know if this is possible to do in iOS, so for the moment I'm stuck with Word and iOS's UIWebView for display.  I have opened a bug report with Apple.

Comment: SeeCoolGuy: makes sense. I didn't realize this was iOS, I only really have a CRL hat :\